# mysqli query returns true but fetch_assoc doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using PHP and MySQL (mysqli) in XAMPP, I have a drop down, and the user must choose one, then a query is used to find the id of the value that has been chosen but it does not work. I have already done this three more times and it worked but this one doesn't.

```
    $sql = "SELECT foo_id FROM foo_table
WHERE foo_name = 'bar';";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++) {
        $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
        echo $row[row["foo_id"]]
    }
```

The problem is that fetch_assoc does not return anything even though the $res variable returns true.

Edit: I forgot to mention that running the query in phpmyadmin returns results normally.

Comment: Why do you do an (incorrect) double index `$row[row["foo_id"]]` ? This even give you warnings (which are bugs in disguise). Check your logs and make your code run without errors, warnings or notices.

Comment: That a `SELECT` query has been executed successfully doesn't mean there is any data in the result set. You can check with the [`num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) field how big the result set is.

Comment: @Progman, if i run the query in phpmyadmin, there is one result, but when i do it in the above code, there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem is that the real database used greek characters in the records and the database had to be set to utf8-bin, after doing so, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are iterating over 500 times? this doesn't make sense.

Best practice to retrieve the data from DB is

```
$sql  = "SELECT foo_id FROM foo_table
          WHERE foo_name = 'bar'";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $row["foo_id"];
   }
 }
```

OR

```
 $foo_id = ''
 if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      $foo_id = $row["foo_id"];
   }
 }
 for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++) {
    echo $foo_id;
 }
```

Comment: this was the original code, the 500 iterations is a result of me trying to solve the problem (on a wrong way (obviously))

Comment: Also, I just noticed that your sample code has $res and $result, i think you forgot to change the name of one of the variables, you might want to edit that